# Android GCM says Error=NotRegistered, but I registered my app

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am new to Android GCM environment.

I am writing java codes to receive GCM message with Google's 'getting started' page. http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

I wrote android client code with them and wrote C# code to send message to GCM server.

My app successfully registered its device and got registration id like `'APA91bGOqUv--of9MyUevAvFq-RNh375O7S5m5y_WvuSwn1zJqbIsGJpzkJda99RIL1jgZ0zC89RC5q8scj3eZMqMeLdTlUsqfSBD_A4jr_000000000000000000000000n_QWhC0Q8KEzQl_icWaBRS4DeMIK_puCzFBO6rArcq8Lax4_YilU'`.

But when my C# code call the GCM server - https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send - to send message, it returns 'Error=NotRegistered'.

I didn't upload my app to official app store, but I don't think it does matter.

Would anyone give me advice to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the reason.

Every time when I try to debug, app need to get registered again.

The registration id above is expired.

I received it again, and it worked well.